# Sitecore Log4net RollingFileAppender not working

Tags: logging

I've trying to implement RollingAppender for general log files in sitecore 8.1 update 2 solutions.

The moment I change below

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

to

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

the log files are not creating.

Exact config I am using in solution is:

```
 <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
    <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.txt&quot;" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50KB" />
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <immediateFlush value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
  </appender>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: by size and date, I mean composite mode

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: Best way to figure out the issue is to enable debug mode of log4net Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems

Comment: Is the datepattern correct? I've done somethign similar before but that property look like:  <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
Do be aware it occasionally stops logging when you recycle application pool.

Answer (score 1):

As you would like to use Composite style, you are missing couple of configuration entries in your config.

You need to change your config like this (change values according to your needs):

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

Take a look in more examples here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html (Search for "RollingFileAppender")

Comment: I've tried te same way. did not work. I've updated the exact config Im using int he question. basically rollingfileappender is not working for me.

Comment: I just found out that the logs are being created at the root of my C drive (c:\data\logs\..) instead of data folder of my sitecore website. any idea why the logs are not going to data folder of website? FYI- I've added this config as a patch config under app_config\includes..

Comment: can you change the file value to "$(dataFolder)/logs/log.txt"

Comment: tried "$(dataFolder)/logs/log.txt", but no luck.. log files are still not going to correct place

Comment: Have you verified (by looking at `ShowConfig.aspx`) that the `<appender>` element and its children are all present and correct?

Comment: I think the RollingFileAppender cannot evaluate the $(dataFolder) only the SitecoreLogFileAppender, so you need to specify the full path of the folder.

Comment: @TamasVargaSitecore - I'll specify full path for now, but out of curiosity, i've tried the same configuration on a fresh Sitecore 8.1 update2 installation, there it logs to the datafolder (with "$(datafolder)/logs/log").

Comment: Best way to figure out the issue is to enable debug mode of log4net

Check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems